# Angular 9 for iterating the OR condition of an array1 to a data array2 and concat the result

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two arrays, one store the conditions and other array contain data objects.
I am looking for a way to iterate through the condition array and if anyone match found, then add them to the result. Below is the function, that I wrote to do this but with always with only one condition i.e. searchableColumns[0]

```
private _filter(value: any): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    var result = this.searchData.filter(option => option[this.searchableColumns[0]].toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    return result;
  }
```

But I want to check for other searchableColumns as well. These matching is an OR condition.
Also When adding to the result, I want to concatenate the object's property as string.

For, example, say I have

```
this.searchData = [{key: "1", name: "One", value: "Once"}, {key: "2", name: "Two", value:"On Twice"}, {key: "3", name: "Three", value: "Thrice"}];
```

and

```
this.searchableColumns = ["name", "value"];
```

and when the function is called with parameter `On`, then the result will be

```
result = ["1|One|Once", "2|Two|On Twice"]
```

as result[0] has name with "On" and result[1] contains value with "On".

Please let me know, if it can be done and can be improvised.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
private _filter(value: any): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    var result = this.searchData.map(item => {
      if(Object.values(item).filter(ele => ele.contains(filterValue)).length){
         return `${item.key} | ${item.name} | ${item.value}`
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also want to consider the array searchableColumns. I tried to fit in the code and working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! You should be able to manipulate this to get the output format you want

```
filter(filterValue){
        let result = []
        let objs = [{key: "1", name: "one", value:"once"}, {key: "2", name: "Two", value:"on twice"}]
        let searchableColumns = ['name', 'value']
        searchableColumns.forEach(column => {
          result.push(objs.filter( obj => obj[column].includes(filterValue)))
        })
        return result
      }
```

Comment: This page really helped me understand the filter function: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to use the code and the result came up with few unmatched data as well. I am working to fit in the code.

Comment: Also to consider the OR condition, Array#some https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some  was working.